# Custom block breaking when sole item in Cover block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I've created a custom block that implements `InnerBlocks` and it's works just fine without error when it's inside a Cover block with a `Paragraph` block as the first child of the `Cover` block.

When my custom block is the sole item in a `Cover` block however, and after I click the `InnerBlock`'s appender button, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

react_devtools_backend.js:2560 The above error occurred in the <UncontrolledInnerBlocks> component:
    in UncontrolledInnerBlocks (created by ForwardRef)
```

My custom block's edit function thus far:

```js
export default function Edit(props) {
  const {clientId, setAttributes} = props;

  return (
    <div {...useBlockProps()} className="simple-carousel-container">
        <InnerBlocks
          orientation="horizontal"
        />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try using just `{...useBlockProps( { className: 'simple-carousel-container' } )}` instead of `{...useBlockProps()} className="..."`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Sally, that was indeed the problem. This works perfectly when it's implemented as:

```js
<div {...useBlockProps({className: "simple-carousel-container"})}>
```

Thanks again :)